# Default shuffle partition value in spark

Tags: apache-spark

The default shuffle partition value in spark is 200 partitions. I would like to clarify that this number is per input partitions ? or across all input partitions, the number of output partitions are going to be 200 ?

I looked at several materials and not able to find the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure whether I understood your question, however I think I can give you a best example I found in [Spark: The Definitive Guide book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/spark-the-definitive/9781491912201/)  to understand number of partitions and corresponding tasks in each stage

[image: example code in Python]

For this job following is the explain output

[image: step4.collect explain output]

This job breaks down into the following stages and tasks:

- Stage 1 with 8 Tasks
- Stage 2 with 8 Tasks
- Stage 3 with 6 Tasks
- Stage 4 with 5 Tasks
- Stage 5 with 200 Tasks
- Stage 6 with 1 Task

  - The first two stages correspond to the range that you perform in order to create your DataFrames. By **default** when you **create a DataFrame with range**, it has **eight partitions**.
  - The next step is the repartitioning. This changes the number of partitions by shuffling the data. These DataFrames are shuffled into six partitions and five partitions, corresponding to the number of tasks in stages 3 and 4.
  - Stages 3 and 4 perform on each of those DataFrames and the end of the stage represents the join (a shuffle). Suddenly, we have **200** tasks. This is because of a Spark SQL configuration. The `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` **default value is 200**, which means that when there is a shuffle performed during execution, it outputs 200 shuffle partitions by default. You can change this value, and the number of output partitions will change.
  - The final result aggregates those partitions individually, brings them all to a single partition before finally sending the final result to the driver.

Another note on `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` from [spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)

`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions    200 Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data **for joins or aggregations**.`